# Division block responsive media query

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am still in the learning process and newbie at Stackoverflow. Sorry about any stupid behavior from my side.

I have a WordPress theme, and it's already responsive . I made a page, where I made 3 boxes (with inline CSS to make their background colorful, and one box floats on right, whereas other 2 float on left).

Please check that page and the 2nd box here : [About Us](http://www.solarkingindia.com/about-us/)

Now, when I check site from mobile, I see that the 2nd box floats on right and goes out of screen. I am not much aware of how division hierarchy work in CSS, so I tried few things in media queries, but I couldn't succeed. I gave that 2nd block `<div id="image2" style=".....;float:right;">`

and now in media query, I want it to be `float:none`;

Can anyone point me to how to do this? What is correct hierarchy that I have to put inside media query (which is there in a theme file).
I managed to change few things with the logo via media query, and I got the idea that I had to write
`.header-wrapper .logo-wrapper {.....}`

I just don't know how to do the exact same thing with this block of text.

Help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your image2 has a fixed width on both mobile and desktop

```
@media (max-width:767px){
/* try this */
 #image2{
    width: 100%;
 }
```

}

My advice to you: AVOID INLINE STYLING...

Comment: Yes, I just figured out that image should be changed, I changed the image (before I had used a background image) and this time I inserted image directly and it aligned itself!
Thank you for the advice! :)
I am bit new, so still learning things slowly, and its really fun, thank you again!